# Set internet priority access on program by program basis

Tags: internet, priority

Is there a way to prioritize which programs are using my bandwidth? For instance I often have background downloads running when I play video games but would like to make sure Dota 2 has all the internet connection it needs. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to prioritize which programs are using my bandwidth?

Yes, you can use QoS settings on your router [HowTo QoS Router](https://www.howtogeek.com/75660/the-beginners-guide-to-qos-on-your-router/) 
However, if you don't have access to your router admin settings, you can still use software which can prioritize bandwidth to user selected applications, see [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/464441/how-can-i-give-a-running-process-priority-for-bandwidth-usage-on-windows) posted on Server Fault website.

Answer (pasted below) was accepted by another user:

> I would take a look at the program Net Limiter, or search for programs similar. 
> Here is a link to Net Limiter. 
> http://www.netlimiter.com/

Hope this helps!

EDIT: While the software QoS service will work for your needs, QoS settings on your router will give you the best results